# Bash code eliminacion de datos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

[image: Esto es lo que me va mostrando pero al añadir un proceso nuevo la tabla se queda vacia]Tengo un código mas arriba en el que recojo los datos por pantalla y los añado a sus respectivos array, el problema surge cuando le digo que si que quiero volver a meter mas, llego a meter hasta 5 pero al meter 6 se me borran, el marcador de total de proceso me muestra  que hay 6 pero no me muestra los 6 procesos introducidos, se han borrado y al meter el Séptimos vuelve a empezar desde 1 proceso y así sucesivamente.

Acabo de añadir el código entero del método que lee por pantalla, el problema es que me hace la lectura bien me lo almacena bien pero al llegar a 6 se elimina todo

```sh
        lectura_datos(){
    # NOS SERVIRA PARA RECORRER TODOS LOS PROCESOS
    seguir=`expr 1`
    i=`expr 0`
    # PARA CREAR LA TABLA
    j=`expr 0`
    o=`expr 1`

    # PARA ALMACENAR EL NUMERO DE PROCESOS
    echo "      >> Numero de procesos: $numProcesos" >> informe.txt

    # PARA ALMACENAR EL QUANTUM
    read -p "Introduce el quantum de ejecución: " quantum

    while ! mayor_cero $quantum
    do
        echo "Entrada no válida"
        read -p "Introduce el quantum de ejecución: " quantum
    done
    echo -n $quantum >> entrada.txt
    printf '\n'>>entrada.txt

    echo "      >> Quantum de tiempo: $quantum" >> informe.txt
    clear
    while [[ seguir -eq 1 ]] ;
    do
        echo $COLOR
        if [ $o -eq 0 ];
        then
            read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P$o: " tiempollegada
        else
            if [ $o -lt 10 ];
            then
                read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P0$o: " tiempollegada
            else
                read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P$o: " tiempollegada
            fi
        fi
        if [ -z $tiempollegada ]; # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
            then    
            tiempollegada=`expr 1`
            else
            # COMPROBACIÓN DE LECTURA
                while ! es_entero $tiempollegada
                do
                    echo "Entrada no válida"
                    if [ $o -eq 0 ];
                    then
                        read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P$o: " tiempollegada
                    else
                        if [ $o -lt 10 ];
                        then
                            read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P0$o: " tiempollegada
                        else
                            read -p "Introduce Tiempo de llegada del P$o: " tiempollegada
                        fi
                    fi
                    if [ -z $tiempollegada ]; then # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                        tiempollegada=`expr 1`
                    fi
                done
            fi
        # Lo pasamos al array
        tiempo_llegada[$i]=`expr $tiempollegada`

        if [ $o -eq 0 ];
        then
            read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$o: " raf
        else
            if [ $o -lt 10 ];
            then
                read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P0$o: " raf
            else
                read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$o: " raf
            fi
        fi

        if [ -z $raf ]; then # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                raf=`expr 1`
            else
            # COMPROBACIÓN DE LECTURA
                while ! es_entero $raf
                do
                    echo "Entrada no válida"

                    if [ $o -eq 0 ];
                    then
                        read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$o: " raf
                    else
                        if [ $o -lt 10 ];
                        then
                            read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P0$o: " raf
                        else
                            read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$o: " raf
                        fi
                    fi

                    if [ -z $raf ] # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                    then
                        raf=`expr 1`
                    fi
                done

                while ! mayor_cero $raf
                do
                    echo "Entrada no válida"

                    if [ $o -eq 0 ];
                    then
                        read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$i: " raf
                    else
                        if [ $o -lt 10 ];
                        then
                            read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P0$o: " raf
                        else
                            read -p "Introduce la rafaga de P$o: " raf
                        fi
                    fi

                    if [ -z $raf ] # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                    then
                        raf=`expr 1`
                    fi
                done
            fi
        # Lo pasamos al array
        rafaga[$i]=`expr $raf`

        if [ $o -eq 0 ];
        then
            read -p "Introduce el tamaño P$o: " tam
        else
            if [ $o -lt 10 ];
            then
                read -p "Introduce el tamaño P0$o: " tam
            else
                read -p "Introduce el tamaño P$o: " tam
            fi
        fi

        if [ -z $tam ]; then # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                tam=`expr 1`
            else
            # COMPROBACIÓN DE LECTURA
                while ! es_entero $tam
                do
                    echo "Entrada no válida"

                    if [ $o -eq 0 ];
                    then
                        read -p "Introduce el tamaño P$o: " tam
                    else
                        if [ $o -lt 10 ];
                        then
                            read -p "Introduce el tamaño P0$o: " tam
                        else
                            read -p "Introduce el tamaño P$o: " tam
                        fi
                    fi

                    if [ -z $tam ]; then # Si la entrada está vacía, valor por defecto 0
                        tam=`expr 1`
                    fi
                done
            fi

        # LO PASAMOS AL ARRAY
        tamano[$i]=`expr $tam`
        echo -n "$tiempollegada $raf $tam" >> entrada.txt
        printf '\n'>>entrada.txt
        clear
        ordenar $i
        i=`expr $i + 1`
        o=`expr $o + 1`
        numProcesos=`expr $i`
        iniciar_colores
        nProceso=`expr 1`
        echo "$NORMAL""$VERDE"
        echo "$NORMAL""$VERDE##################################"
        echo    ">>>>> Quantum: "$quantum
        echo    ">>>>> Total proceso: "$numProcesos
        echo "$NORMAL""$VERDE##################################"
            echo "$NORMAL""$VERDE Rej Tll Tej Mem $NORMAL"
            for (( j = 0 ; j <$i ; j++ ))do
                tiempos_ejecucion[$j]=`expr 0`
                enumProceso[$j]=$nProceso
                if [ ${enumProceso[$j]} -le 9 ] && [ ${enumProceso[$j]} -ge 0 ]; then
                        str="${colores_procesos[$j]} P0"${enumProceso[$j]}
                    else
                        str="${colores_procesos[$j]} P"${enumProceso[$j]}
                    fi
                    if [ ${tiempo_llegada[$j]} -le 9 ] && [ ${tiempo_llegada[$j]} -ge 0 ]; then
                        str=$str" "${tiempo_llegada[$j]}" "
                    else
                        str=$str" "${tiempo_llegada[$j]}
                    fi

                    if [ ${rafaga[$j]} -le 9 ] && [ ${rafaga[$j]} -ge 0 ]; then
                        str=$str"  "${rafaga[$j]}" "
                    else 
                        str=$str"  "${rafaga[$j]}
                    fi

                    if [ ${tamano[$j]} -le 9 ] && [ ${tamano[$j]} -ge 0 ]; then
                        str=$str"  "${tamano[$j]}"$NORMAL"
                    else
                        str=$str"  "${tamano[$j]}"$NORMAL"

                    fi
                    echo -e "$str"
                nProceso=$((nProceso+1))
            done
            echo "$NORMAL""$VERDE##################################$NORMAL"
            echo

        error_seguir=1
        while [[ error_seguir -eq 1 ]]
        do
            read -t 300 -p "Añadir nuevo proceso  1-Si / 2-No "  seguir
            if [[ $seguir -eq 1 || $seguir -eq 2 ]] 
            then 
                error_seguir=0
            else
                echo "Error en la entrada de datos. Introduce un numero valido"
            fi
        done
    done

    #ORDEANR $i
    i=`expr $i - 1` # PARA QUE EN EL BUCLE DE ABAJO FUNCIONE EN EL INFORME
    #PARA EL INFORME
    echo "" >>informe.txt
    echo "               ----ORDEN DE ENTRADA EN LA MEMORIA----">>informe.txt
    echo "" >>informe.txt
    echo "                  Proceso  tiempo  rafaga  tamaño" >>informe.txt
    for (( j = 0; j <=$i ; j++ )) 
    do
            echo "                  P"${orden[$j]}"        "${tiempo_llegada[orden[$j]]}"        "${rafaga[orden[$j]]}"       "${tamano[orden[$j]]} >>informe.txt
        done
  }
```

Comment: Iría bien un [mcve] para ver cómo ejecutas, qué te da y qué querrías. También es bueno mostrar solo el código relevante

Comment: exactamente es el código donde da problemas, y no encuentro la solución por mas vueltas que le de

Comment: te falta algo de codigo en la parte de arriba (no se ve el while que deberia cerrarse en el ultimo done). por lo que veo estas con un problema de coals de procesos de tipo Round-robin con quantum=1. Por favor, pon el codigo completo para que se pueda ver.

Comment: ya esta el código completo

Comment: no podemos leer un código de 200 líneas para encontrar un error. Es por ello que sugería un [mcve]. En cualquier caso, https://www.shellcheck.net siempre es de ayuda: pega tu código allí y te indicará los errores generales